# How to find the number of every length of contiguous sequences of values in a list?

Tags: python

## Problem

Given a sequence (list or numpy array) of 1's and 0's how can I find the number of contiguous sub-sequences of values? I want to return a JSON-like dictionary of dictionaries.

## Example

`[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` would return

```
{
  0: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2
  },
  1: {
        2: 1,
        3: 1
  }

}
```

## Tried

This is the function I have so far

```py
def foo(arr):
    prev = arr[0]
    count = 1

    lengths = dict.fromkeys(arr, {})

    for i in arr[1:]:
        if i == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count in lengths[prev].keys():
                lengths[prev][count] += 1
            else:
                lengths[prev][count] = 1

            prev = i
            count = 1

    return lengths
```

It is outputting identical dictionaries for 0 and 1 even if their appearance in the list is different. And this function isn't picking up the last value. How can I improve and fix it? Also, does numpy offer any quicker ways to solve my problem if my data is in a numpy array? (maybe using `np.where(...)`)

Comment: can you explain more on output?

Comment: Sure of course. Let's say my list has a run of 2 zeroes, 2 ones, 1 zero, 3 ones, then 2 zeros. Then I want the output to tell me that for zeroes I have 1 run of 0's, and 2 runs of two 0's. For ones I have 1 run of two 1's and 1 run of three 1's. Preferably, this would be outputted in a nested dictionary/JSON-like format but any other way is fine too. Hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suffering from Ye Olde Replication Error.  Let's instrument your function to show the problem, adding one line to check the object ID of each dict in the list:

```
lengths = dict.fromkeys(arr, {})
print(id(lengths[0]), id(lengths[1]))
```

Output:

```
140130522360928 140130522360928
{0: {2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1}, 1: {2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1}}
```

The problem is that you gave the *same* dict as initial value for each key.  When you update either of them, you're changing the *one* object to which they both refer.

Replace it with an explicit loop -- not a mutable function argument -- that will create a new object for each dict entry:

```
for key in lengths:
    lengths[key] = {}
print(id(lengths[0]), id(lengths[1]))
```

Output:

```
139872021765576 139872021765288
{0: {2: 1, 1: 1}, 1: {2: 1, 3: 1}}
```

Now you have separate objects.

If you want a one-liner, use a dict comprehension:

```
lengths = {key: {} for key in lengths}
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't even think that would have been the problem. That fixes it, thank you so much. Is there a better way to create a nested dictionary like this from a list of keys?